# Anomalous base pairing of nucleotide tautomers

Tags: biochemistry, dna, organic-chemistry, nucleic-acids

What tautomers base pair with what bases?

I know that adenine pairs with thymine and guanine pairs with cytosine normally. My question is what does the *imino* form of adenine base pair with? Regular cytosine? What does the enol form of guanine base pair with? Regular form of thymine?

I cannot find any books discussing this issue and Google is of no use. However, my professor wants us to know how tautomers base pair.

I tried base pairing cytosine with adenine but does the -NH2 group on cytosine really hydrogen bond with the imino -NH group on the adenine tautomer?

Comment: http://blc.arizona.edu/courses/181Lab/MoBiByMe/Tautomers.html

Answer (score 3):

The tautomers are rare but they can form and it is suggested that tautomerization can lead to mutations because of non-cognate base pairing.

[Khuu & Ho (2009)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19580331), have inferred the presence of adenine and thymine tautomers from the crystal structure of an *in-vitro* assembled holliday junction. They infer that *imino*-Adenine base pairs with *amino*-cytosine (normal form) and *enol*-thymine base pairs with *keto*-guanine (normal form).

[image]

> Reproduced from: **[Khuu & Ho (2009)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19580331)**

---

<sub>Khuu, P., & Ho, P. S. (2009). [**A rare nucleotide base tautomer in the structure of an asymmetric DNA junction**](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19580331). *Biochemistry*, 48(33), 7824-7832.</sub>